# Transfer wordpress to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I transferred the this site http://www.mouratovalawfirm.com on the local host
I made a backup site and database 
in the database, I changed all url - http://www.mouratovalawfirm.com on localhost/mouratova
when I go on home page all is ok, when i go on another page (example localhost/mouratova/immigration) i see blank page

when i go in admin area i see this error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
" Z:\home\localhost\www\mouratova\wp-content\plugins\sitepress-multilingual-cms\inc\hacks.php:67") in Z:\home\localhost\www\mouratova\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1751

In site was using wpml plugin, maybe problem with this.
Tell me please
what I did wrong?

Comment: Try resetting permalinks. Set it to default and check if its working. Then reset permalink to whatever type u want, then save and check.

Comment: Why not use wordpress built in import/export function. Pranita also has a valid point here.

Comment: Hi, Pieter. I was do it. Content is copy right. But the theme of is not displayed correctly.